# Wordpress AJAX not passing POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am integrating AJAX into a WordPress plugin with the following code:

PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );

function myajax_submit() {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $months = $_POST['months'];

    echo('<b>£'.$amount.' over '.$months.' months</b>');

    wp_die();
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery("button.compareLoans").click(function() { 
       jQuery.post(
        MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        {

            action : "myajax-submit",

            postID : MyAjax.postID,
            data: "amount="+$( "input#loan-amount" ).val()+"&months="+$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )
        },
        function( response ) {
            $("#content_update").html(response);
        }
);
 });
```

The issue I have is that the 'amount' and 'months' variable is not passing through, these come through as blank and the return is simply '£ over months' so missing the variables completely.

Really not sure what the issue is here, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending the data properly. If you checked your `$_POST` you will have a value for `$_POST['data']`

```
jQuery("button.compareLoans").click(function() { 
       jQuery.post(
        MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : "myajax-submit",
            postID : MyAjax.postID,
            amount : $( "input#loan-amount" ).val(),
            months : $( '#slider' ).slider( "value" ),
        },
        function( response ) {
            $("#content_update").html(response);
        }
    );
});
```

Additionally you should be using [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) with [check_ajax_referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) for security.

Don't forget to [validate and sanitize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) your variables server side too.

Comment: @JamesLeist Glad to help. Please mark the answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you may want to stick with using the property 'data', you can try:

```
function myajax_submit() {
    $amount = explode('=', explode('&', $_POST['data'])[0])[1];
    $months = explode('=', explode('&', $_POST['data'])[1])[1];

    echo('<b>£'.$amount.' over '.$months.' months</b>');

    wp_die();
}
```

It just simply parses the string value of *data*, which would allow you to get the values of *amount* and *months*, through an array.